# how to configure gtalk and jabber in asterisk

Tags: gmail, asterisk

I set all configuration in asterisk and working fine all but when i load module jabber then getting error like:

```
[Nov 14 17:21:38] ERROR[2991]: res_jabber.c:1694 aji_act_hook: JABBER: encryption failure. possible bad password.
[Nov 14 17:21:38] ERROR[2991]: res_jabber.c:1577 aji_act_hook: aji_act_hook was called with out a packet
[Nov 14 17:21:38] WARNING[2991]: res_jabber.c:1392 aji_recv: Parsing failure: Hook returned an error.
[Nov 14 17:21:38] WARNING[2991]: res_jabber.c:2743 aji_recv_loop: JABBER: Got hook event.
[Nov 14 17:21:38] WARNING[2991]: res_jabber.c:2754 aji_recv_loop: JABBER: socket read error
```

I create new gmail account but error like bad password and i set correct password then also i getting error:

My jabber.conf

```
[gtalk_account]
type=client
serverhost=talk.google.com
username=myid@gmail.com/Talk
secret=password
port=5222
usetls=yes
usesasl=yes
buddy=mydi@gmail.com
statusmessage=”This is an Asterisk server”
timeout=100
```

My gtalk.conf

```
[buddy]
username=myid@gmail.com
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
context=google-in
connection=gtalk_account
```

when i load module then getting error message like above.

can any buddy have solution for this error.

Comment: is @secret=password@   correct?

Comment: What does `jabber show connections` return?

Comment: its return nothing and i think this issue may version of asterisk

Answer (score 0):

Acordinly to asterisk doc  you put incorrect username

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google#CallingusingGoogle-XMPPConfiguration

I think config you used not valid anymore.

Note, i just tested that config and got errors like you show, but also i got from google answer why it not working. Google say "we detected account login attempt" and "blocked it".

I.e current google account protection resulting gtalk not working on asterisk server if you use same account from other ip.